# Pattern Recognition - Visualizing Dense Data Points

Tags: density-function, large-data, pattern-recognition

I have a sample of around 5000 data (2D) points that are generated through a simulation of a cryptocurrency's mining events of following form.

In column 2 one can see identical y-values with different x-values yet being "densely packed" and consequently becoming "invisible" among the large sample after plotting.

```
column 1:         column 2:
time in s*60      height of created "coins"
341.00000         1 
345.02802         1 
2621.00000        2 
4180.00000        3 
4183.87060        3 
...
3016703.00000     3993 
3016708.45441     3994 
3019167.00000     3995
3019170.07885     3995
```

**Question:** I need to visualize the pattern of identical y-values with slight time difference but don't know if there's a method/tool to make this pattern clearly noticeable.

*Note*: The pattern mentioned before makes up about 20% of all events with a "sub-pattern" making up 6% of all events, with both patterns being almost uniformly distributed among all events.

I'd just like to make the pattern visible, be it by coloring or any other method, but I'm quite new to plotting tools like python's pylpot so I'm lacking seach terms that would help me.

**What I have tried so far:**
- multiplied the x value in the simulation script causing a "scissor" in the plot.
- thought of a density plot

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just asking for a `time` by `height` scatterplot in which you can see that there are multiple instances at certain points?

Comment: Maybe plot the points with some transparancy, then where there are many points overlapping you will get a darker value.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21314508/489448 for an example (in R, I don't know python plotting).

Comment: Try to subsample your data and then visualize it. Perhaps you don't need to plot all data points.

Comment: @gung yes, but it's more important to me to make the pattern recognizeable possibly at first sight.

Comment: @kasterma thanks, i'll do some research on the transparency approach, good idea!

Comment: @xeon I'd like to keep the sample size but kind of mark the dense parts.

Comment: A word to search on is "jitter".

Answer (score 3):

Heat maps are preferred for very large datasets; transparency is great, but works up to a point - a certain degree of juxtaposition cannot be visualized without the 3D component. In R smoothScatter () is great, several examples for Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313905/how-to-set-ggplot-alpha-transparency-value-for-all-points-at-once/21314508#21314508). Bubble charts may also work for some applications.